# How retrieve json element by key (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, key-value

I would like to retrieve option with key '2021-05-14' from this json-object.

```
{
  stock: {
    zip: '95014',
    lastUpdated: '05/02/2021'
  },
  options: [
    { '2021-05-07': [Object] },
    { '2021-05-14': [Object] },
    { '2021-05-21': [Object] },
    { '2021-05-28': [Object] },
    { '2021-06-04': [Object] },
    { '2021-06-18': [Object] }
  ]
}
```

I tried:

```
var options;
var expirationSeries;
options = res.body.options;  // res.body is the json-object
for (var key in options)
{
  if (key=='2021-05-14') {
    expirationSeries = options[key];
  };
}
console.log(expirationSeries);
```

but then I get error 'undefined'.

How to do this properly?

Comment: Did you debug your code or add `console.log(key)` to see what it returns? You need to loop through the array and check if each object has the key `'2021-05-14'`

Comment: it's seems like your JSON options is array of json objects so key is a number, not a date as you mention above.

Comment: This can be done in several ways, but maybe with a slight change in your code this could even be simpler. If the order of your `options` collection is not important, you could turn this into an object instead of an array, and simply have `options{'2021-05-07': [Object],'2021-05-14': [Object],'2021-05-21': [Object]}`, achieving what you want to do simply using `options['2021-05-14']`

Comment: Use `console.log` to see what you're getting.  Note that `for (var k in ["first", "second"]) {
` will give `0, 1` so I think you'll find that key is a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `for (var key in options)` over an array will assign the indices of the array to `key` variable.

You could use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop and use `hasOwnProperty` to check if the object has that date as property. Since you want only one match, you could `break` if a match is found

```js
for (const o of options) {
  if (o.hasOwnProperty('2021-05-14')) {
    expirationSeries = o
    break;
  }
}
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
let options = [{"2021-05-07":{foo:"bar"}},{"2021-05-14":{foo:"bar"}},{"2021-05-21":{foo:"bar"}},{"2021-05-28":{foo:"bar"}},{"2021-06-04":{foo:"bar"}},{"2021-06-18":{foo:"bar"}}],
    expirationSeries;
  
for (const o of options) {
  if (o.hasOwnProperty('2021-05-14')) {
    expirationSeries = o
    break;
  }
}

console.log(expirationSeries)
```

---

You could use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to get the object which has the specified key. If multiple objects can have that key, use `filter` to get all the matches

```js
const expirationSeries = options.find(a => a.hasOwnProperty('2021-05-21'))
const allMatches = options.filter(a => a.hasOwnProperty('2021-05-21'))
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const options = [{"2021-05-07":{foo:"bar"}},{"2021-05-14":{foo:"bar"}},{"2021-05-21":{foo:"bar"}},{"2021-05-28":{foo:"bar"}},{"2021-06-04":{foo:"bar"}},{"2021-06-18":{foo:"bar"}}],
    expirationSeries = options.find(a => a.hasOwnProperty('2021-05-21')),
    allMatches = options.filter(a => a.hasOwnProperty('2021-05-21'))

console.log(expirationSeries)
console.log(allMatches)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since options is an array you can use find to get the first object that has a property key in it.

```js
const jsonData = {
  stock: {
    zip: '95014',
    lastUpdated: '05/02/2021'
  },
  options: [
    { '2021-05-07': {} },
    { '2021-05-14': {} },
    { '2021-05-21': {} },
    { '2021-05-28': {} },
    { '2021-06-04': {} },
    { '2021-06-18': {} }
  ]
 }

const key = '2021-05-21';

const result = jsonData.options.find(option => key in option );

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `for...in` you can try using `for...of`.

**Demo:**

```js
var options;
var expirationSeries;
options = [
    { '2021-05-07': 'data 1' },
    { '2021-05-14': 'data 2' },
    { '2021-05-21': 'data 3' },
    { '2021-05-28': 'data 4' },
    { '2021-06-04': 'data 5' },
    { '2021-06-18': 'data 6' }
  ]
for (var obj of options)
{
  var k = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  if (k=='2021-05-14') {
    expirationSeries = obj[k];
  };
}
console.log(expirationSeries);
```

**OR:** You can try using `.find()`

```js
var options = [
    { '2021-05-07': 'data 1' },
    { '2021-05-14': 'data 2' },
    { '2021-05-21': 'data 3' },
    { '2021-05-28': 'data 4' },
    { '2021-06-04': 'data 5' },
    { '2021-06-18': 'data 6' }
  ];
var temp = options.find(o => Object.keys(o)[0] === '2021-05-14');
var expirationSeries =  temp != undefined ? Object.values(temp)[0] : 'not found';
console.log(expirationSeries);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
options.forEach(obj => {
  const key = Object.keys(obj)[0];

  if (key == '2021-05-14') {
    expirationSeries = options[key];
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the object within the options array. Something like:

```js
const fromJson = {
  stock: {
    zip: '95014',
    lastUpdated: '05/02/2021'
  },
  options: [
    { '2021-05-07': {} },
    { '2021-05-14': {} },
    { '2021-05-21': {} },
    { '2021-05-28': {} },
    { '2021-06-04': {} },
    { '2021-06-18': {} },
  ]
}

const expirationSeries = findOptionByKey(`2021-05-14`);
console.log(expirationSeries);

// not found
console.log(findOptionByKey(`2022-03-12`));


function findOptionByKey(key2Find) {
  const keyFinder = obj => obj[key2Find];
  return fromJson.options.find(keyFinder) || `option [${key2Find}] not found`;
}
```